# first-child selector means what? Select the first-child of the element? Or select it if it is the first-child?

Tags: jquery, selector, css-selectors

Look at this:

```
var selection= $('table td:first-child');
```

In practice it selects the first row's `<td>` elements in the table.

When I saw it for the first time, I took it as: Select all first-child elements within all `<td>` in the `<table> </table>`.

But what it does is: Select all `<td>` within the table if it is the first-child of its parent. Means first `<td>` between each  tags.

So, the question is, does first-child selector works like a flag? Or it works like a kind of method to get the first-child of the element in question in the jQuery wrapper-set?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstchild will get the `TD` within the table that are the first child within their parent. If you wanted what you intially though it'd be something like `table td > *:first-child`. Think of it like the rest of the `:` filters jQuery provides: hidden, disabled, checked, etc. It applies to the element in the selector it is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

the `:first-child` selector can match more than one: one for each parent. This is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)`.

source: [here](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).